# Symfony 3.1: Unable to find the controller for path "/logout"

Tags: php, symfony, logout

I am trying to get my logout functionality done using Symfony 3.1, but it has not working so far. I am following the book documentation step by step but all I am getting is a not found exception:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/logout". The route is wrongly
>   configured.

I do activate the correct config parameter (logout) in the security.yml file

```
security:
       firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false

            main:
                anonymous: ~
                # activate different ways to authenticate
                form_login:
                    login_path: login
                    check_path: login
            secured_area:
                anonymous: ~
                logout:
                    path:   /logout
                    target: /
```

And I do create a route inside routing.yml:

```
logout:
    path: /logout
```

And that's it according the documentation, no controller is needed, but the exceptions says that controller path is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is because you have two firewalls defined.  For the moment, get rid of the secured_area stuff and try something like:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:  ^/
        anonymous: ~
        switch_user: true

        form_login:
            provider:            user_provider
            login_path:          user_login
            check_path:          user_login_check
            default_target_path: app_welcome

            username_parameter:  username
            password_parameter:  password

            csrf_parameter:       _csrf_token
            csrf_token_id:        authenticate
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

        logout:
            path:   user_logout
            target: app_welcome
```

Notice that the logout section is under the main firewall.  Once you have the main firewall working then you can try adding the secured_area back in if you really need it.

And yes I got lazy and just copied/pasted a working configuration.  You will have to tweak the routes to match yours.

Comment: After few changes (I remove csrf stuff and the provider) it worked!   But why is used the secured area in the documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: I can understand the confusion.  Configuring the security component can be challenging.  And the documentation is not 100% consistent.  Consider contributing to the documentation effort: http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/documentation/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for top answer which is right. There is another trick you should be aware of:
**Make sure that /logout is behind a firewall. /logout path has to match a firewall pattern.**

Ex: 'pattern: ^/admin' then logout path should be '/admin/logout'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use two firewalls, it is likely that you also want two login forms with two logout routes.

It is important to add the connection routes is disconnect in the "pattern" for which is recognized by each firewall

Routing configuration :

```
# config/routes.yaml
logout_medical:
  path: /logout-medical

logout_patient:
  path: /logout-patient

# I omitted the declaration of the connection routes because they are made with annotations in the controllers
```

Firewall configuration :

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
  # ...

  firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    main:
      pattern: ^/(logout-medical|login-medical|m)
      anonymous: ~
      provider: medical_provider
      form_login:
        login_path: login_medical
        check_path: login_medical
      logout:
        path: logout_medical
        target: login_medical

    patient_area:
      pattern: ^/(logout-patient|login-patient|p)
      anonymous: ~
      provider: patient_provider
      form_login:
        login_path: login_patient
        check_path: login_patient
      logout:
        path: logout_patient
        target: login_patient
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a controller associated with that route most likely.
If you are using a bundle like FOSUser you just need to import the routing.yml provided by the bundle. If you don't have any bundle/controller to take care of that route you must implement one.

Comment: Indeed, I don't have a controller associated to that route since the cookbook says that (a controller) is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

To add more detail to Cerad's answer: a security user in Symfony is bound to a "security context" which, by default, corresponds to a firewall.  In your case, you wish to log out of the context ("firewall") that you have imposed the form_login authentication requirement on, and so your logout configuration needs to be set on the "main" firewall, not on a new one called "secured_area".

The documentation uses the firewall name "secured_area" merely as a way of indicating that this config is intended to be used in a firewall which acts to secure a part of your website. It's not intended that you copy that name literally into your config; rather, in your case, the firewall which you're trying to secure is called "main".  In this sense, the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) is a little confusing because everywhere else it uses only a firewall called "main" for its examples, including for examples where it sets up a secured area. So I guess it might be better if it used "main" in this particular example.

Additionally, you need to ensure that the logout route (path) is actually handled by the firewall for which you have configured it, rather than be "caught" by a different firewall.  In your case this will happen automatically, because you have not imposed any path restriction on your "main" firewall and so it catches everything.